# Are browser plugins, such as Silverlight, supported in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, internet-explorer

These is a question. And MS give the following answer:
"Internet Explorer provides an add-on–free experience, so browser plugins don't load and any dependent content isn't displayed. However, Internet Explorer for the desktop does support browser plugins, including ActiveX controls such as Adobe Flash and Microsoft Silverlight. For more information, see Browsing Without Plug-ins on IEBlog. "
(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846773.aspx)

So should we take it as NO?
And what does it mean "Internet Explorer for the desktop"?

Comment: There are two versions of IE10: the Metro version (accessed from the Windows 8 Start screen) and the Desktop version which presumably will run on W7 and in the W8 desktop

Comment: See here for list of compatible and supported browsers:
http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx (click "System Requirements" tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Windows Store app, i.e. such as you might have on a tablet device, it runs in plug-in free mode. But on a PC, it doesn't unless you set it to. So Silverlight and other plugins are still fully supported in IE10 for a PC.

Comment: It's funny when Microsoft does not support their own technology.